# How to merge multiple dataframes with different rows using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following dataframes in R, which all have a different number of rows and different dates in them as well.

```
data1 <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(18628, 18629, 18630, 18631), class = "Date"), 
    Value1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

data2 <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(18628, 18632, 18633), class = "Date"), 
    Value2 = c(1, 2, 3)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

data3 <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(18626, 18629, 18633, 18634, 
18635), class = "Date"), Value3 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I would like to combine all three of them into one dataframe. Usually, I would use `full_join` for this but that's only possible for two dataframes, like this

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- full_join(data1, data2, by = 'Date') %>% 
  arrange(Date)
```

Is there a simple way in which I can merge more than 2 dataframes into one dataframe?

Comment: are you expecting to have output with NA's as demonstrated by your `data` object?  You now have three answers two that do not and one that does.

Comment: Yes I am expecting to have NA's in my merged dataframe line in Mael's solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Collect your data frames in a list and use `reduce`:

```r
mget(ls(pattern = "^data")) %>% 
  reduce(full_join, by = "Date")

# A tibble: 9 × 4
  Date       Value1 Value2 Value3
  <date>      <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 2021-01-01      1      1     NA
2 2021-01-02      2     NA      2
3 2021-01-03      3     NA     NA
4 2021-01-04      4     NA     NA
5 2021-01-05     NA      2     NA
6 2021-01-06     NA      3      3
7 2020-12-30     NA     NA      1
8 2021-01-07     NA     NA      4
9 2021-01-08     NA     NA      5
```

Comment: Thanks Mael, this is what I'm looking for! Just a quick question, is there a way to pass the names of the dataframes into a list as opposed to using ```pattern = ''^data''))```? Because in my actual code my dataframes aren't named by a distinct pattern

Comment: Yes, use list(data1, data2…)

Answer (score 1):

Using `base R`

```
Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all = TRUE), mget(ls(pattern = "^data\\d+$")))
```

-output

```
        Date Value1 Value2 Value3
1 2020-12-30     NA     NA      1
2 2021-01-01      1      1     NA
3 2021-01-02      2     NA      2
4 2021-01-03      3     NA     NA
5 2021-01-04      4     NA     NA
6 2021-01-05     NA      2     NA
7 2021-01-06     NA      3      3
8 2021-01-07     NA     NA      4
9 2021-01-08     NA     NA      5
```

---

Or with `plyr::join_all`

```
plyr::join_all(mget(ls(pattern = "^data\\d+$")), type = "full")
        Date Value1 Value2 Value3
1 2021-01-01      1      1     NA
2 2021-01-02      2     NA      2
3 2021-01-03      3     NA     NA
4 2021-01-04      4     NA     NA
5 2021-01-05     NA      2     NA
6 2021-01-06     NA      3      3
7 2020-12-30     NA     NA      1
8 2021-01-07     NA     NA      4
9 2021-01-08     NA     NA      5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in base R quite simply:

```
group_data<-rbind.data.frame(data1,data2,data3)
group_data
```

Comment: Apologies I had to edit my post to rename the value columns in each dataframe. I would like to merge the dataframes so that each of the ''Value'' columns are adjacent to each other with NA values, like in Mael's solution above

Answer (score 0):

```
full_join(data1, data2) %>% 
  full_join(., data3)
Joining, by = "Date"
# A tibble: 9 × 4
  Date       Value1 Value2 Value3
  <date>      <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 2021-01-01      1      1     NA
2 2021-01-02      2     NA      2
3 2021-01-03      3     NA     NA
4 2021-01-04      4     NA     NA
5 2021-01-05     NA      2     NA
6 2021-01-06     NA      3      3
7 2020-12-30     NA     NA      1
8 2021-01-07     NA     NA      4
9 2021-01-08     NA     NA      5
```

Comment: Apologies I had to edit my post to rename the value columns in each dataframe. I would like to merge the dataframes so that each of the ''Value'' columns are adjacent to each other with NA values, like in Mael's solution above

Comment: The second part of your solution almost gets me to what I need, the only issue is that some of the rows (Dates) are duplicated when binding them this way